# 'Not only you are right, but also he is right.' Can I change it to 'Not only you but also he is right'?

Tags: ellipsis, parallelism

> 1. Not only you are right, but also he is right.

Can I change it to the following?

> 2. Not only you but also he is right.

Comment: "Not only you are but he is also right."  Using not only...but also, this seems to be the only option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both examples in the original post are grammatically correct.  I find the first example to be easier to understand.

An idiomatic phrasing is as follows:

> 3. You're both right.

Example 3 is not as formal as either of the original post's examples.  The following version is just as formal as the original post's examples:

> 4. You are both right.

In the Southern dialect of American English, the following two versions are acceptable.  However, they are not Standard Written English, so they are less formal than any of the first four examples:

> 5. Y'all are right.
> 6. Y'all are both right.

Comment: I'd have ended this answer at 3)  The others are not really needed.

Comment: Why are your 3 and 4  same? May you tell me why not say: " Not only are you right, but also he is right."?

Comment: @Y.zeng — 3 & 4 are different.  3 uses a contraction; 4 does not.  The contraction makes 3 less formal than 4.

Comment: @Y.zeng — As explained in the answer, your option #1 is grammatically correct, and easier to understand than option #2.  It is just not idiomatic.

Comment: Is this (Not only you but also he is right.)  right? It means **You is right.** in some situations.